# my react-table is not getting populated with data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-table, react-context

I am working on a simple table where i am using react-table-6 package.Its a class component where i have maintained my state and doing a componentDidMount and setState.

my table is not getting populated with data and initially i was getting response where i have consoled response but now i am getting 404 error.The data which i get from the backend is a simple array of objects and there is no nested object in it.

This is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "../bin/api/config";
import ReactTable from "react-table-6";
import "react-table-6/react-table.css";
export default class ReactTableComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("hello");
    axios
      .get("/admin/users", {
        headers: { Authorization: localStorage.getItem("authToken") }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response", response);
        const users = response.data;
        this.setState({ users });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: "Email",
        accessor: "email"
      },
      {
        Header: "Phone No",
        accessor: "phone"
      },
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstname"
      },
      {
        Header: "Second Name",
        accessor: "lastname"
      },
      {
        Header: "Street",
        accessor: "street"
      },
      {
        Header: "Zip",
        accessor: "zip"
      },
      {
        Header: "City",
        accessor: "city"
      }
    ];
    return <ReactTable columns={columns} data={this.state.users} filterable />;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no `resolvedData` variable used in your code. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the response you log?

Comment: now the error is not there but still my table is not getting populated with data

Comment: So what are the contents of `response` and `response.data` when you don't receive fetch error?